# Difference between enum class method in Kotlin for calling constant name

Tags: kotlin, enums

Im new in kotlin, i was trying enum class and i found that these 3 method return the same thing.

```
package com.example.test1

fun main() {
    println(Direction.valueOf("NORTH")) // print NORTH
    println(Direction.NORTH)            // print NORTH
    println(Direction.NORTH.name)       // print NORTH
}

enum class Direction(var direction: String, var distance: Int) {
    NORTH("North", 20),
    SOUTH("South", 30),
    EAST("East", 10),
    WEST("West", 15);
}
```

What is the difference uses between them?

Comment: Good question indeed, because it allows one to dive into implementation details of Kotlin enums. I would also add println(Direction.NORTH.toString()) to the question to cover this case as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Direction.valueOf("NORTH")` returns value of enum class `Direction` by it's `name`. When you call `println` it implicitly calls `toString` method (that every Kotlin object implements implicitly). And `toString` default implementation for `enum class` is enum's name. You can override this method if you want.
- `Direction.NORTH` it's actual enum instance. Like I wrote previously `println` implicitly calls `toString` method
- `Direction.NORTH.name` returns `name` field of type `String`. It is special field, every `enum class` has, that returns it's name

For example if you change `enum class` like this:

```kotlin
enum class Direction(var direction: String, var distance: Int) {
    NORTH("North", 20),
    SOUTH("South", 30),
    EAST("East", 10),
    WEST("West", 15);

    override fun toString(): String {
        return this.name.lowercase()
    }
}
```

first two prints will be `"north"`